# Bootstrap table cell align crashes with img-responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to align 3 divs vertically in a row. The table-cell works fine but if I use this method to align vertically, then the responsiveness doesn't work.

This is the code:

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
               <p>some text</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
               <p>some text</p>
          </div> 
          <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
               <img class="img img-responsive" src="/theme_classy/static/img/clock2.png"/>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

The css is the following:

```
.row {
display: table;
}
.col-md-4 {
float: none;
display: table.cell;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Because of the float none in mobile view the cols are next to each other and not on top of them.
I've tried lots of things but none of them helped. Could you suggest me something?

Comment: Look into media queries. That will solve your problem.

Comment: is this your real code or a typo? table.cell should be table-cell

Comment: I think you shouldn't try to redefine Bootstrap classes. Not sure how to fix it though without using JavaScript or flexbox.

Comment: Sorry, this is a typo since I didn't want to paste a big piece of code here

Answer (score 0):

just change

```
.col-md-4
{
display: table-cell;
}
```

to

```
.col-md-4
{
display: table-row;
}
```

i tried this and it works fine for me